# Suppose $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers. Show that $xy$ odd implies that $x$ and $y$ are both odd.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Is my following proof correct using the contrapositive method?

***Contrapositive Statement:***

Suppose $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers. Show that $x$ or $y$ is even implies that $xy$ is even.

***Proof:***

For $x,y\in \mathbb{N}$, assume, without loss of generality, that $x$ is even. Then $x=2m$ for some $m\in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore,$$xy=(2m)y=2r,$$ where $r=my\in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, $xy$ is even.

Comment: This looks good to me. I especially like that you used the contrapositive rather than deriving an unnecessary contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is fine. I like the insight of choosing to use the contrapositive - that's a skill that will serve you well, because it makes the proof swifter and more elegant here, in my personal opinion.

It *might* be worth spelling out in your proof that this in the contrapositive, and thus implies the result you intended to prove, just for completeness' sake, though. A minor nitpick but nothing huge.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! It's really boosting my proof writing confidence :)